# Mootools class binds with element as parameter

Tags: javascript, mootools

Is it possible to send over the target of an event bound to a mootools class with Binds?

ie:

`checkbox.addEvent('change', this.checkBoxChangeAgain(this));`

Where `this` == `checkbox`

ps. This doesn't work:

`checkbox.addEvent('change', this.checkBoxChangeAgain(checkbox));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason why it does not work is that by doing `method(this)` you actually invoke it immediately. `method.bind(checkbox)` will decorate the function and change the scope to be the checkbox when it does get called later.

why not proxy it?

```
var self = this;
checkbox.addEvent('change', function(e) {
    self.checkBoxChangeAgain(this);
});

new Class({
    checkBoxChangeAgain: function(checkbox) {
        this; // instance
        checkbox; // == org checkbox 
    }
});
```

by default the first argument to an event handler will be the event and the scope will be the trigger element.

hence:

```
checkbox.addEvent('change', this.checkBoxChangeAgain);
```

will mean that:

```
new Class({
    checkBoxChangeAgain: function(event) {
        this === event.target; 
    }
});
```

which means you can also:

```
checkbox.addEvent('change', this.checkBoxChangeAgain.bind(this));
```

and that will work out as:

```
new Class({
    checkBoxChangeAgain: function(event) {
        this != event.target; // true
        event.target === checkbox; // true
        this; // the class instance
    }
});
```

I hope this gives you ideas. Also, search for bindWithEvent here on SO - in particular, replacement for bind with event.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually got around it by using pass. You're answer pointed me in the right direction though.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to how Dimitar's answer works, but using Class.Binds, the easiest way is to use `.pass()` http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Function#Function:pass

`this.checkBoxChangeAgain.pass(checkbox)`

Comment: reliance on `Class.binds` is generally frowned upon as it does not promote good readability, particularly in a long class, as well as performance - cheapest way to fix is by passing a reference to this in a variable. all methods are already wrapped once...